# XPages SSJS: what can prevent a page to enter edit mode when opeing with URL?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a view where I build a URL that should open a document in edit mode.  My page has its default action property set to open the document but I thougn that since I am specifying in the URL that I want to open in edit mode, it would work, but the document is opened in read mode.

Do I need an extra SSJS line of code to switch the document mode to verify the parameter when the page is opened?

Here is the code in my view's column:

```
"/page.xsp?action=editDocument&documentId=" + rowVar.getDocument().getUniversalID();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem...  This line was causing the problem in the custom control's datasource's definition :

```
ignoreRequestParams="true"
```

Worked as expected once set to false!  The thing is, I think, that property is only visible in source mode.  Not sur ewhy it was set to false: I must have tried something before...

Comment: Makes sense. Ignorerequestparams= false will map your data source to the documentid you have in the url.  Nice to hear you solved it.

Comment: Note:  typically you want that setting to be true if you have multiple dataSources on your page.

Answer (score 0):

check the document data source in the document XPage. It must be set to edit mode.

Comment: But that will set the edit mode for each time the document is opened, right?  That is not what I want: I need the document to be edited only by users that have a specific role, and opened in read mode by all the others.  This view is only available to these content editors, but I'll be validating the role when building the URL in the view, just in case some non editor user gets to the view somehow.

Comment: You forgot to mention that in the question